# Labeling empty Shield UI ASP.NET charts

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

How can I put a label on a Shield UI ASP.NET chart that contains no data at the moment? I have a couple of charts on a web page but don’t want them to display data until the user decides to. For instance I need to put “Click to show information” or similar. 
I tried to add additional DIV’s above the chart, but it doesn’t  work fine…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use the primaryHeader property in order to display that information. When refreshing the chart you shall substitute that text with the actual header text.
Furthermore- you may also use the secondaryHeader to provide additional instructions to the user if needed.